# Syntax Highlighthing in TeXstudio: "unregognized command"

Tags: texstudio

Codes are working correctly, but some codes have colored boxes on them.
[image]
[image]
[image]\

E.G code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.1pt}
\newcounter{numex}
\def\thrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.5ex depth \dimexpr0pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}

\newcommand\Startex{%
    \stepcounter{numex}
    \begin{center}
    \textsc{\bfseries ~\thenumex)}~{\thrulefill}
    \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
%
\vspace*{0.2cm}
\Startex
\hspace{1.2cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\tkzDefPoint(-8,4){A},
\tkzDefPoint(-7.07,10.43){B},
\tkzDefPoint(1.1,4.01){C},
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
\tkzLabelSegment[left,font=\footnotesize](A,B){$3,9$\,cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[below,font=\footnotesize](A,C){$9,1$\,cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[right,font=\footnotesize](B,C){$10,4$\,cm}
\draw[very thick,black](-8,4)--(-7.08,10.43)--(1.1,4.01)--cycle;
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1.4cm,very thick,black,samples=99](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=2](A,B,C){$\alpha$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyone to help?

Comment: Welcome! How could anyone help if you did not ask a proper question? =) These colored boxes seem to be code highlighting and futher they seem to denote that the code has some error, I assume? Now, you want this highlighting to go away, because, obviously there is no error? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @JasperHabicht When I write the code in overleaf, these colored boxes are not there. But when i write in tex studio there are red boxes. But the code is working.

Comment: It is not easy to know why exactly this happens since I don't know your code completely. But, it seems it is a problem related to TeX Studio's highlighting procedures then. If the code compiles file and does not throw any errors, you should just ignore this. Code highlighting (in Overleaf as well) only can do a guess about the code, since it does not compile the code in the background. Therefore, sometimes, the marking of errors may be not fully correct.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), that shows the problem. Usually, that syntax highlighting means "command unknown". This can happen, if the command is defined in another file that is used with `\input` or a file that is used there. But if the compiles correctly, you can just ignore it. Then it's a inaccuracy of the editor.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes it can be, thank you

Comment: I added @dexteritas

Comment: Your question is just about syntax highlighting in one specific editor and you didn't even mention the editor you are using in the question.

Comment: [TeXstudio - A LaTeX Editor / Wiki / Frequently Asked Questions: Why does TeXstudio mark a command as unrecognized?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-texstudio-mark-a-command-as-unrecognized)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes thank you everyone